# How to use Google Web Fonts "text" parameter on Blogger?

Tags: google, fonts, template, blogger, xml

Google introduced the new parameter "text" to the Google Web Fonts API, where you can choose which letters will come from your request (for when you only need few letters for the logo)

The introdution of the new parameter is explained [here](http://googlewebfonts.blogspot.com/2011/04/streamline-your-web-font-requests.html)

But if I insert this Blogger Template:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Over+the+Rainbow:regular&text=PulaAe' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

I get this error:

```
The reference to entity "text" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Someone knows how is the right way to use this new parameter within Blogger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reference to entity "text" must
>   end with the ';' delimiter.

This appears to be an HTML validation error.

Try this `<link>` instead:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Over+the+Rainbow:regular&amp;text=PulaAe' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```